# Знак вопроса и код

Tags: обсуждение, форматирование, стиль

Иногда в предложении хочется добавить код, выделенный в отдельный блок (т.е. не `внутрестрочный`), но само предложение является при этом вопросительным. Т.е. в конце должен бы быть знак `?`. Например:

> [image: пример]

Знак вопроса на отдельной строке выглядит странно, но он же всё таки должен быть. Как можно оформлять подобные предложения на SO, чтобы они не были вырвиглазными, но соответствовали по большей части правилам русского языка?

Comment: Отметил вопрос свежеизобретённой меткой. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin стиляга!

Comment: Мне интересно ваше мнение: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5158

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Может быть использовать вопросительный знак **вместо** двоеточия?

> Что означает следующий код?
>
> ```
> int a;
> ```

Comment: [Так?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wurld.png)

Comment: @alexolut [Примерно](http://imgur.com/a/jcuWO)

Comment: Самое логичное построение вопроса + пример, из предложенных трех. Коротко и ясно, и по порядку. 
Знак вопроса должен быть, в конце вопроса, а не после примера.

Answer (score 3):

Можно разместить вопрос **после** блока кода:

> ```
> int a;
> ```
>
> Что означает вышеприведённый код?

Comment: Можно и так. Кстати, цитирование почему-то обрезает выделение кода. Именно поэтому я привёл картинкой в вопросе.

Comment: @alexolut косяк с CSS, разметка правильная :)

Comment: в андроидном приложении в этом плане [лучше](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QujOX.jpg).

Comment: В мобильной версии [тоже](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qSsp.png).

Comment: @alexolut помнится, когда-то фон таких блоков совпадал с фоном цитат, и на это были жалобы. И вот, пофиксили таким странным образом.

Comment: Если блок кода довольно большой, то читатель некоторое время будет в недоумении.

Comment: @D-side запилил, кстати, [баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295584/339911) по поводу разметки на мете.