# Метка для руководств по стилю написания текстов (не кода) на сайте

Tags: предложение, метки, создание-метки

На Мете уже есть вопросы о том, как лучше писать вопросы и ответы, справку, локализованные строки и другие тексты на сайте.

В написании структурированных нехудожественных текстов такие рекомендации и правила обычно называются «руководством по стилю» ("style guide"), а в журналистике являются частью редакционной политики. Аналог в программировании — стиль кодирования.

Давайте объединим эти вопросы одной осмысленной меткой. Пока что придумал название [стиль](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c) и отметил десяток вопросов.

Задачи:

- Придумать название метки — **предлагайте варианты в ответах**.
- [Сделать хорошее описание метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/272).
- Найти и отметить подходящие вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом согласен. Но если затрагивать ещё и справку, и интерфейс, то придётся эту метку довесить на множество вопросов с меткой [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f). Если это не простой [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82), конечно.

Может быть стоит разделять рекомендации/предложения по стилю пользовательского контента от стиля внутренних страниц сайта. Как, например, мы закрываем глаза на использование `е` вместо `ё` в сообщениях участников, но при этом [желаем видеть её на внутренних страницах сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3960/176217). Аналогично для выбора обращения [Вы/вы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/489/176217).

Comment: Большинство вопросов про локализацию — либо дефекты, либо выбор перевода. Они к этой метке не относятся. Меньшинство вроде [глоссария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1135/181472) — годятся, можно отметить.

Comment: По одному голосу. Всем пофиг на стилистику. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin всем пофиг на Мету. Интерес в основном только к [meta-tag:драма] вопросам. И прочим социальным темам.

Comment: С опозданием, но принято.

Comment: Надо бы назначить синоним [meta-tag:драма] или [meta-tag:oh-noes-teh-drama] для какой-нибудь скандальной метки.